# How intrinsic dimensions are computed for SVG images?

Tags: html, svg

[HTML 5 specifiction](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-img-element.html#dom-img-naturalwidth) defines that:

> The IDL attributes `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` must return the intrinsic width and height of the image, in CSS pixels, if the image is available, or else 0.

It's clear how intrinsic width and height for JPG, PNG, GIF are computed - they all have fixed dimensions in px. But I can't find how these dimensions are computed for SVG images.

I've made an experiment with arbitrary SVG image and it returns different values in different browsers:

- Chrome - 137 x 150
- Firefox - 0 x 0
- Safari - returns dimensions of the DOM element instead of intrinsic dimensions

So is there any specification defining how it should behave? And why Chrome is returning these values? I can understand behavior implemented in Safari and Firefox, but Chrome is doing something interesting.

```js
const width = document.getElementById('img').naturalWidth;
const height = document.getElementById('img').naturalHeight;

document.getElementById('result').innerText = `Width: ${width}\nHeight: ${height}`;
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Chrome starts from the values that would be given if you embedded something whose size could not be worked out.

Those values are [300 x 150px](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width).

It then looks like it's applying the aspect ratio from the viewBox to the 150px width to generate a new height of 150 x 96 / 105 = 137.142px which I guess it rounds to 137px

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Image object **without** putting it into the DOM. Then the image will have the correct natural width.

```
var i = new Image();
i.src = document.getElementById('img').src;
i.naturalWidth
```